# Проблема с ionic build

Tags: cordova, ionic

Собственно консоль

```
sudo ionic build android

Running command: /home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test/hooks/after_prepare/010_add_platform_class.js /home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test
add to body class: platform-android
ANDROID_HOME=/root/Android/Sdk
JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0.
     Required by:
         :android:unspecified
      > Could not GET 'https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/1.5.0/gradle-1.5.0.pom'.
         > peer not authenticated

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

BUILD FAILED

Total time: 1.615 secs
ERROR building one of the platforms: Error code 1 for command: /home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Error: Error code 1 for command: /home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/home/aiduryagin/Desktop/androidDev/test/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true
```

Может, кто-то сталкивался с подобным?

Comment: ошибка — *could not get https://... peer not authenticated*. возможно, это была временная ошибка. возможно, постоянная. связанная, например, с попытками перехвата https, например, в вашей сети, или у вашего провайдера.

Comment: Мне помогла эта [статья](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38140783/errorfailed-to-resolve-com-google-android-gmsplay-services-measurement9-2-0).
 Так же я обновил кордову.